# Play framework for production application on GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, playframework

We are creating Google App Engine application on java. We are looking into Play! framework 1.2.x (http://www.playframework.org/) and we're in process of making some tests with it. Our main concern is about maturity of Play! framework and the future support on GAE module (as I see it's still not supported in Play! version 2).

Does anyone has experience with production projects with Play on GAE? And if so, will Play! be your choice if you start the project today?

Comment: Why GAE? There are lots of PaaS providers, so why not choose your framework/language and then choose the best supported platform?

Answer (score 2):

I have used GAE for a simple web-page, but there are a number of things that are lost because of the restrictions of GAE. Therefore, when running into problems, it is sometimes difficult to know if it is Play (less likely) or GAE (most likely). I don't think there is good enough support, to be honest.

That said, I would still use Play for any web development, but choose something like Heroku, CloudBees, OpenShift or one of the many supported platforms. There are a number of platforms also supporting Play 2.0.

As for future support, there is no word on GAE for Play2.0, but I would be very surprised if a GAE module is created, as the benefits of Play 2.0 over Play 1.x cannot be realised because of the restrictions of GAE, so I don't see the point.